# Using Node/Angular, how do I make a call to an api (using methods from a node module) and have the data sent to the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, node-modules

I am trying to use angular + node and am making a method call to a JS Api. 
It returns data in my index.js file that I want to be made available in my angular module for attachment to the $scope.

My two approaches/attempts have been to:

1) Inject the hiw-api module as a factory parameter (won't work/how do won't pick up my module.
2) Use RequireJS to include node module hiw-api (too complex)

My goal is that once the data is in the $scope I can manipulate it, I just can't seem to get it there. Any help would be greatly appreciated! [index.js Github](https://github.com/hopeatina/HIW/blob/master/routes/index.js), [index.html](https://github.com/hopeatina/HIW/blob/master/public/javascripts/controllers/main.js) (if you dare)

```
var hiw = require("hiw-api");
var apiKey = "da45e11d07eb4ec8950afe79a0d76feb";
var api = new hiw.API(apiKey);
var http = require("http");

exports.index2 = function (req, res) {

    var rawresponse;
    var founderror;
    var indicatorDescription;
    var locales;
    //var allinidcatorsURL = '/Indicators/ { page }?Key= { key }';
    //var filter = new hiw.Filter()
    //    .addEqual(hiw.Locale.Fields.ScriptFullName, "Arkansas");


    hiw.Synchronizer.sync([
        hiw.IndicatorDescription.getByID(279, api, function (data, response, error) {
            indicatorDescription = data;

            console.log(indicatorDescription.fullDescription);
            console.log(indicatorDescription);
            title = "Express"; //response: rawresponse, error: founderror


        }),
        hiw.Locale.getAll(api, function (data, response, error) {
            locales = data; //Array of Locale
            //console.log(locales);
        })
    ], function (data) {

        res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
        //res.json(locales);

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `HIWmethods` defined as a service correctly, you have to inject it in the controller like this:

```
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'HIWmethods', function($scope, HIWmethods) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.loading = true;

        // GET =====================================================================
        // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
        // use the service to get all the todos
        $scope.test = "Hello world!!!!!!!!!!"
            HIWmethods.getLocales().then(function(data) {
                $scope.locales = {
                    availableOptions: data
        }
                $scope.loading = false;
            });

    }]);
```